# An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelValidationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Error-An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelValidationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
MVCApplication.Models.Employee: : EntityType 'Employee' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
Employees: EntityType: EntitySet 'Employees' is based on type 'Employee' that has no keys defined.

controller code:

```
namespace MVCApplication.Controllers
{
    public class EmployeeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Employee
        public ActionResult Detail(int id)
        {
            EmployeeContext employeecontext = new EmployeeContext();
            Employee emp = employeecontext.Employees.Single(x => x.Emp_Id ==id);//here its throwing an exception
            return View("employee",emp);
        }
    }
```

this is my model employee class:

```
namespace MVCApplication.Models
{
    [Table("Employee")]
    public class Employee
    {
        public int Emp_Id { get; set; }
        public string Emp_Name { get; set; }
        public string Designation { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
    }
}
```

this is my employee context class:

```
namespace MVCApplication.Models
{
    public class EmployeeContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to set attribute `[Key]` to your model, like this

```
[Table("Employee")]
public class Employee
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int Emp_Id { get; set; }
    public string Emp_Name { get; set; }
    public string Designation { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

Use `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` only if your database generate ids, if not you just `[Key]` attribute.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sousuke for your precious time. It successfully solved the problem. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have set the auto increment attribute to 'Emp_Id' column in your database table, and your model should look like this:

```
[Table("Employees")]
public class Employee
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int Emp_Id { get; set; }
    public string Emp_Name { get; set; }
    public string Designation { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```